# ogr.driver.Open() not working on second execution

Tags: pyqgis, ogr

I have the following code.

```py
fn = 'C:/temp/file.shp'
layerfields = QgsFields()
layerfields.append(QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int))
layerfields.append(QgsField('ELEV', QVariant.Double))

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(fn, 'UTF-8', layerfields, QgsWkbTypes.LineString,
                         QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'ESRI Shapefile')

del(writer)                             



# Open Layer in OGR

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.Open(fn, 1)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
Dst_Layer = ds.GetLayer()
       
layer_iface = iface.addVectorLayer(fn, dst_layer_name, 'ogr')
```

The code works perfectly fine when it is executed for the first time. However, if I execute it again, it produces an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'
```

The problem seems to be in driver opening the file the second time, when it is already opened. The error goes away when I delete the opened layer (due to layer_iface expression). However, deleting the same layer through the python script prior to the above code block does not fix the error.

Furthermore, I tried to execute this block twice using a for loop. Lets say first execution is execution 1 that has this block loop twice A and B. Then second execution 2 that had this block loop twice A and B.
I expected the code to run perfectly on run 1A but encounter an error on run 1B, 2A and 2B. However, the runs 1A and 1B run smoothly, and the error occurs on 2A, 2B.

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem, but I do think it's got something to do with closing the driver.Open(fn, 1) line.

Can you help me out here?

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: The error is generated at `Dst_Layer = ds.GetLayer()` However, the actual problem is at `ds = driver.Open(fn, 1)` Here, Open function is not working

Comment: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#is-ogr-driver-available-by-driver-name shows how to check if the driver is available

Comment: I used that to check if the driver is available. It shows that it is available both the occasions, when the file is opened, and when the file fails to open.